# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file numpart.mdf failed. it is located on UNC share

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my app.config I wrote the following code

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="numpart"
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDbFilename=numpart.mdf;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But I got the following error.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file numpart.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share. How can I solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Using the Attachdbfilename property requires the full path to the database file not only the file name. Take note that the path cannot exceed 128 characters.

Try to replace attachtodatabas=numpart.mdf with DataBase=numpart and see if that works better.